# Getting "No such file or directory" when deleting directories with find

Tags: files, find, rm

I'm using Amazon Linux. I have this statement that is designed to remove files in a directory

```
/bin/find $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs -mindepth 1 -mmin +1441 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

But this results in a bunch of statements like this

```
/bin/find: `/usr/java/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment2b6836209f40596a': No such file or directory
/bin/find: `/usr/java/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/deployment1fae3ca49edb3384': No such file or directory
/bin/find: `/usr/java/jboss/standalone/tmp/vfs/deploymenta2b0c99bfdd7f444': No such file or directory
...
```

Is there a way to have my statement not scan files that don't exist, or at least eliminate all these errors?

Comment: Add a `-prune` after the `-exec ... \;` so `find` doesn't attempt to descend into the directories you've just removed.

Comment: Or do a depth-first search so deeper stuff is dealt with first.

Comment: As a note, to get rid of any error statements from the output at the end of almost any statement, pipe `stderr` to `/dev/null`. `2> /dev/null`

Answer (score 4):

Beware that your command removes directories that haven't changed in a day, even if some files under them have changed recently.

Assuming that this is what you want, [Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%c3%a9phane-chazelas) and [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/128228/thrig) have proposed two solutions in comments. The problem you're facing is that you instruct `find` to delete a directory, and then it tries to traverse it to see if there are any files in it that would match.

- Pass `-depth` to tell `find` to process a directory's contents first and the directory itself last. This wastes a bit of time analyzing the contents of directories that will be removed just later.

  ```
  find $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs -depth -mindepth 1 -mmin +1441 -exec rm -rf {} \;
  ```
- Use `-prune` to instruct `find` not to explore the directories that are getting removed.

  ```
  find $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs -mindepth 1 -mmin +1441 -exec rm -rf {} \; -prune
  ```

If you only meant to delete old files, then let `find` know. You can use `-delete` instead of invoking `rm`.

```
find $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs -mmin +1441 -type f -delete
```

You can then remove empty directories:

```
find -depth $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs -type d -empty -delete
```

Or combine the two, deleting directories after any file in them that should be removed has been removed:

```
find $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/tmp/vfs -depth -mindepth 1 -mmin +1441 -type f -delete -o -type d -empty -delete
```